# Find column vectors contained in B but not in A - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have matrix `A` of size `10x100` and matrix `B` with size `10x200`.

How to find the column vectors contained in `B` but not in `A`? ( A and B do not have the same number of columns)

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html `setdiff(A,B) returns the data in A that is not in B.` Transpose matrix if needed.

Comment: @Cheery: setdiff(A,B) when A and B are matrices with the same number of columns. This is not the case here!

Comment: Do you see a sentence about the transpose of matrix? rotate it and you will have the same number of columns.

Comment: If either of the solutions provided here work for you, consider accepting one of those, so that Stackoverflow would consider this question as a "closed" case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to elaborate @Cheery's comment with an example.

```
A=[1;4];
B=[1 2 4;4 5 6];
C=setdiff(B',A','rows')';
```

more details see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html

Comment: +1 Potentially faster: `B(:,~ismember(B.',A.','rows'))`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** here -

```
Bout = B(:,all(any(bsxfun(@ne,B,permute(A,[1 3 2])),1),3))
```

Sample run -

```
A =
     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     1     1     1
     1     1     2     1     3
B =
     3     2     3     2     1     2     2
     3     1     3     1     1     1     3
     2     3     1     2     1     2     3
Bout =
     3     3     1     2
     3     3     1     3
     2     1     1     3
```

Comment: what is the benefit of using a code more complex compared to the other answer?

Comment: @bzak I think for me, it's brings on a bit of learning experience to try out different approaches to solve a problem and a bit of fun too. But agreed that the other solution is more "readable" for this problem :)

Comment: Thank you anyway for your answer :)